# чем отличаются green threads, task-based parallelilism от native threads?

Tags: многопоточность

Хочу уточнить некоторые моменты

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что green threads это "эмуляция" нативных потоков с помощью корутин? например, генераторы в python или javascript это green threads?
2. Правильно ли, что task-based параллелилизм это "эмуляция" потоков без создания своего стека? Если да, то как такое с нуля реализовать (сама идея).

Буду рад ссылкам, проясняющим эти моменты, возможно я чего-то сам не нашел.

p.s. возможно стоит изменить вопрос: fiber отличается ли от концепции task-based параллелизма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

green thread - это реализация потоков на уровне приложения. То есть, с точки зрения операционной системы их нет. Поэтому, когда операционная система делает планирование переключения потоков, она не выделяет на каждый из них время. Если один зеленый тред заблокируюется в системном вызове - все заблокируется.

task-based параллелилизм - это когда мы создаем не треды (и мучаемся с их синхронизацией), а делаем мелкие задачи, которые приложение разбрасывает между тредами. Эти треды (потоки) входят в пул (набор) и их кол-во, запуск-останов полностью управляется приложением (фреймворком). При этом сами задачи об этом не знают. При мелких задачах можно получить хорошую производительность (относительно запуска потока на каждую мелкую задачу).

Генераторы в питоне вряд ли являются зелеными тредами. Хотя, это все зависит от того, как это все понимать.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что green threads это "эмуляция" нативных потоков

вот если так оборвать - то все ок.

корутины- это те же зеленые потоки. Но они могут быть и реальными потоками.

> Правильно ли, что task-based параллелилизм это "эмуляция" потоков без создания своего стека?

нет. Это выполнение задач без понимая того, что есть вообще треды и сколько их. А при чем здесь стек - я не знаю. Может имелось ввиду стек потока?

Comment: Корутины - это не потоки. Формально, это функции со множественными точками входа и выхода. В отличии от остальных терминов, корутины являются фичей языка а не его рантайма.

Comment: @KoVadim, по поводу task-based: имелось ввиду, что при запуске нативной нити у нее есть свой стек потока, но общее адресное пространство с другими нитями, а при task-based для задачи нету своего стека... и я вот думаю как такое возможно вообще?

Comment: Таски используют стек того потока, в контексте которого он запущен.

Comment: @KoVadim, хм, если гринтредов нету в точки зрения ос, то чем тогда таски(их так же нету с точки зрения ос) от гринтредов отличаются?

Comment: Green thread для программиста выглядят как будто настоящие потоки. Таски с точки зрения программиста вообще не связаны с  потоками, хотя обычно в них выполняются. Это позволяет использовать один и тот же поток для многих тасок.

Comment: @KoVadim, хм, благодарствую